# SimpleButton Not Displaying

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm just trying to get a SimpleButton to appear on the stage in an AS3 project. For some reason, it won't appear. Can anyone see why?

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
//Main class:
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import view.controls.CustomButton;
import view.controls.Button;

public class ButtonTest extends Sprite
{
    //private var myCustomButton:Button = new Button();
    private var myCustomButton:CustomButton; 

    public function ButtonTest()
    {
        myCustomButton = new CustomButton("Hello", 0xFF0000);
        addChild(myCustomButton);

    }
}
}

//Custom Button Class:

package view.controls
{
import flash.display.GradientType;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;

public class CustomButton extends Sprite
{
    private var textColor:uint = 0x000000;
    private var myColor:uint = 0xFF0000;
    private var btnWidth:Number = 30;
    private var btnHeight:Number = 18;
    public function CustomButton(buttonText:String, gradientColor:uint)
    {
        var colors:Array = new Array();
        var alphas:Array = new Array(1, 1);
        var ratios:Array = new Array(0, 255);
        var gradientMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
        var myColor:uint = 0xFF0000;
        gradientMatrix.createGradientBox(btnWidth, btnHeight, Math.PI/2, 0, 0);
        //
        var ellipseSize:int = 2;
        var btnUpState:Sprite = new Sprite();
        colors = [0xFFFFFF, myColor];
        btnUpState.graphics.lineStyle(3, brightencolor(myColor, -50));
        btnUpState.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, colors, alphas, ratios, gradientMatrix);
        btnUpState.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, btnWidth, btnHeight, ellipseSize, ellipseSize);
        btnUpState.addChild(createButtonTextField(buttonText, textColor));
        //
        var btnOverState:Sprite = new Sprite();
        colors = [0xFFFFFF, brightencolor(myColor, 50)];
        btnOverState.graphics.lineStyle(1, brightencolor(myColor, -50));
        btnOverState.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, colors, alphas, ratios, gradientMatrix);
        btnOverState.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, btnWidth, btnHeight, ellipseSize, ellipseSize);
        btnOverState.addChild(createButtonTextField(buttonText, textColor))
        //
        var btnDownState:Sprite = new Sprite();
        colors = [brightencolor(myColor, -15), brightencolor(myColor, 50)];
        btnDownState.graphics.lineStyle(1, brightencolor(myColor, -50));
        btnDownState.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, colors, alphas, ratios, gradientMatrix);
        btnDownState.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, btnWidth, btnHeight, ellipseSize, ellipseSize);
        btnDownState.addChild(createButtonTextField(buttonText, textColor))
        //
        var myButton:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton(btnUpState, btnOverState, btnDownState, btnOverState);
        myButton.name = buttonText;
        myButton.height = btnHeight;
        myButton.width = btnWidth;


    }



    private function createButtonTextField(Text:String, textcolor:uint):TextField {
        var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
        myTextField.textColor = textcolor;
        myTextField.selectable = false;
        myTextField.width = btnWidth;
        myTextField.height = btnHeight;
        var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        myTextFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
        myTextField.defaultTextFormat = myTextFormat;
        Text = "<b>"+Text+"</b>";
        myTextField.htmlText = '<font face="Arial">'+Text+'</font>';
        myTextField.x = (btnWidth/2)-(myTextField.width/2);
        return myTextField;
    }

    private function brightencolor(color:int, modifier:int):int {
        var hex:Array = hexToRGB(color);
        var red:int = keepInBounds(hex[0]+modifier);
        var green:int = keepInBounds(hex[1]+modifier);
        var blue:int = keepInBounds(hex[2]+modifier);
        return RGBToHex(red, green, blue);
    }

    private function hexToRGB (hex:uint):Array {
        var colors:Array = new Array(); 
        colors.push(hex >> 16);
        var temp:uint = hex ^ colors[0] << 16;
        colors.push(temp >> 8);
        colors.push(temp ^ colors[1] << 8);
        return colors;
    }

    private function keepInBounds(number:int):int {
        if (number < 0)    number = 0;
        if (number > 255) number = 255;
        return number;
    }    
    private function RGBToHex(uR:int, uG:int, uB:int):int {
        var uColor:uint;
        uColor =  (uR & 255) << 16;
        uColor += (uG & 255) << 8;
        uColor += (uB & 255);
        return uColor;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the created `SimpleButton` object `myButton` to the `CustomButton`'s display list:

```
    // ...
    var myButton:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton(btnUpState, btnOverState, btnDownState, btnOverState);
    myButton.name = buttonText;
    myButton.height = btnHeight;
    myButton.width = btnWidth;

    addChild( myButton );
}
```

Although in your case, maybe you should think about making the CustomButton extend the SimpleButton instead.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I had already added the customButton to the main class and thought that would do it. I'm trying to understand why it is necessary to add it both within the CustomButton class, and then again in the main class. After all, if you create an object with a bunch of properties and then add that object to the display list, it ought to display. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Well you add a customButton to the main class, but the customButton itself is not automatically a button. Your code just says that it is an empty Sprite with some properties inside; but it doesn't display anything. To fix that, you have to add something to the Sprite's display list: in your case a SimpleButton. What you were expecting is that CustomButton is a button itself, but to be that, you should extend the SimpleButton instead.

Comment: So let me summarize my understanding.If the custombutton extended simplebutton, it would automatically appear when I added it to the main class because simplebutton is on the displaylist. Since I didn't extend simplebutton, my custombutton wasn't showing up -- even though I added it as a child to a sprite, which is itself on the displaylist. More generally, is it the case that a sprite will not display unless it adds a child which is on the displaylist?

Comment: *“even though I added it as a child to a sprite”* – Exactly that is the problem. You created an object in the constructor of CustomButton, but you didn't add it as a child to its display list. To make something visible it needs to be on the display list of something else that is visible.